# oneself + gerund

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, gerunds, adjective-phrases, absolute-construction

The U.S. Postal Service, **itself** **teetering** on the brink of insolvency, is ill equipped to handle the surge.  Why not “**its** **teetering** on the brink of insolvency or **it** **teetering** on the brink of insolvency?”  I’d like to know how the grammar works and how to apply it appropriately.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Reflexives like "itself" may be either complements or optional modifiers used for **emphasis**. In your example, "itself" is a modifier, and thus is optional. If we drop it, what we have left is "teetering on the brink of insolvency", which has the same core meaning but without the emphasis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possessive pronouns are appropriate to use with nouns, and a gerund is a participle being used as a noun. But, in this sentence, "teetering" is not a gerund because it is not being used as a noun. The subject of this sentence is the "U.S. Postal Service." The participle here is being used here as an adjective. The word "itself" is not grammatically necessary. The meaning is

> The U.S. Postal service, [which is] teetering on the brink of insolvency, is ill equipped to handle X [because it has no money to spare].

The "itself" is not playing a needed grammatical role. It is playing a rhetorical role with respect to "Postal Service." One bankrupt cannot help another bankrupt. The "itself" is drawing a parallel to some other situation that presumably is clear from context that you have failed to provide. The postal service itself is as financially stressed as whatever is being talked about.

I think the word "gerund" is confusing. Present participles can be used as part of a verb, as an adjective, or as a noun. Here the participle is being used as an adjective, and adjectives do not go with possessive pronouns. Nouns do go with possessive pronouns so "its" would be appropriate when a participle is used as a noun.